# Преобразование JSON в DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, анализ-данных

Как преобразовать json в DataFrame - pandas?

При запросе получаю json данные:

```
[{'ship_id': 'AMERICANCHAMPION',
  'ship_name': 'American Champion',
  'ship_model': None,
  'ship_type': 'Tug',
  'roles': ['Support Ship', 'Barge Tug'],
  'active': False,
  'imo': 7434016,
  'mmsi': 367020820,
  'abs': 571252,
  'class': 7604342,
  'weight_lbs': 588000,
  'weight_kg': 266712,
  'year_built': 1976,
  'home_port': 'Port of Los Angeles',
  'status': '',
  'speed_kn': None,
  'course_deg': None,
  'position': {'latitude': None, 'longitude': None},
  'successful_landings': None,
  'attempted_landings': None,
  'missions': [{'name': 'COTS 1', 'flight': 7},
   {'name': 'COTS 2', 'flight': 8}],
  'url': 'https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/shipid:434663/vessel:AMERICAN%20CHAMPION',
  'image': 'https://i.imgur.com/woCxpkj.jpg'},
 {'ship_id': 'AMERICANISLANDER',
  'ship_name': 'American Islander',
  'ship_model': None,
  'ship_type': 'Cargo',
  'roles': ['Dragon Recovery'],
  'active': False,
  'imo': None,
  'mmsi': 367035570,
  'abs': None,
  'class': None,
  'weight_lbs': None,
  'weight_kg': None,
  'year_built': None,
  'home_port': 'Port of Los Angeles',
  'status': '',
  'speed_kn': None,
  'course_deg': None,
  'position': {'latitude': None, 'longitude': None},
  'successful_landings': None,
  'attempted_landings': None,
  'missions': [{'name': 'CRS-1', 'flight': 9},
   {'name': 'CRS-2', 'flight': 10},
   {'name': 'CRS-3', 'flight': 14},
   {'name': 'CRS-4', 'flight': 18}],
  'url': 'https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/shipid:435112/vessel:AMERICAN%20ISLANDER',
  'image': 'https://i.imgur.com/jmj8Sh2.jpg'}
```

Необходимо из этих данных вытащить 'missions'. На основании его данных создать DataFrame, который будет содержать столбцы Name и Flight.

Мой код

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import json

data = requests.get('https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/ships').json()
df_g = [ch.get('missions') for ch in data]
```

После генератора списков получаю:

```
[[{'name': 'COTS 1', 'flight': 7}, {'name': 'COTS 2', 'flight': 8}],
 [{'name': 'CRS-1', 'flight': 9},
  {'name': 'CRS-2', 'flight': 10},
  {'name': 'CRS-3', 'flight': 14},
  {'name': 'CRS-4', 'flight': 18}],
 [{'name': 'CASSIOPE', 'flight': 11}],
 [],
 [{'name': 'FormoSat-5', 'flight': 46},
  {'name': 'Iridium NEXT Mission 3', 'flight': 48}],
 [{'name': 'CRS-5', 'flight': 19},
  {'name': 'DSCOVR', 'flight': 20},
  {'name': 'CRS-6', 'flight': 22},
  {'name': 'CRS-7', 'flight': 24},
  {'name': 'SES-9', 'flight': 27},
  {'name': 'CRS-8', 'flight': 28},
  {'name': 'JCSAT-2B', 'flight': 29},
  {'name': 'Thaicom 8', 'flight': 30},
  {'name': 'ABS-2A / Eutelsat 117W B', 'flight': 31},
  {'name': 'CRS-9', 'flight': 32},
  {'name': 'JCSAT-16', 'flight': 33},
  {'name': 'SES-10', 'flight': 38},
  {'name': 'BulgariaSat-1', 'flight': 42},
  {'name': 'Boeing X-37B OTV-5', 'flight': 47}],
 [{'name': 'JCSat 18 / Kacific 1', 'flight': 86},
  {'name': 'Starlink 3', 'flight': 89},
  {'name': 'Starlink 4', 'flight': 90}],
 [{'name': 'KoreaSat 5A', 'flight': 50},
  {'name': 'Paz / Starlink Demo', 'flight': 56},
  {'name': 'Iridium NEXT Mission 5', 'flight': 58},
  {'name': 'Iridium NEXT Mission 6', 'flight': 62},
  {'name': 'Iridium NEXT Mission 7', 'flight': 66},
  {'name': 'SSO-A', 'flight': 71},
  {'name': 'STP-2', 'flight': 81},
  {'name': 'Amos-17', 'flight': 83},
  {'name': 'Starlink 1', 'flight': 84},
  {'name': 'JCSat 18 / Kacific 1', 'flight': 86},
  {'name': 'Starlink 2', 'flight': 87},
  {'name': 'Starlink 3', 'flight': 89},
  {'name': 'Starlink 4', 'flight': 90}],
 [{'name': 'ArabSat 6A', 'flight': 77},
  {'name': 'Starlink v0.9', 'flight': 79},
  {'name': 'STP-2', 'flight': 81},
  {'name': 'Amos-17', 'flight': 83},
  {'name': 'Starlink 1', 'flight': 84},
  {'name': 'Starlink 2', 'flight': 87}],
 [{'name': 'TESS', 'flight': 60},
  {'name': 'Bangabandhu-1', 'flight': 61},
  {'name': 'SES-12', 'flight': 63},
  {'name': 'Telstar 19V', 'flight': 65}],
 [{'name': 'CRS-5', 'flight': 19},
  {'name': 'DSCOVR', 'flight': 20},
  {'name': 'CRS-6', 'flight': 22},
  {'name': 'CRS-7', 'flight': 24},
  {'name': 'SES-9', 'flight': 27},
  {'name': 'CRS-8', 'flight': 28},
  {'name': 'JCSAT-2B', 'flight': 29},
  {'name': 'Thaicom 8', 'flight': 30},
  {'name': 'ABS-2A / Eutelsat 117W B', 'flight': 31},
  {'name': 'CRS-9', 'flight': 32},
  {'name': 'JCSAT-16', 'flight': 33},
  {'name': 'SES-10', 'flight': 38},
  {'name': 'BulgariaSat-1', 'flight': 42},
  {'name': 'Boeing X-37B OTV-5', 'flight': 47},
  {'name': 'SES-11 / Echostar 105', 'flight': 49},
  {'name': 'SES-16 / GovSat-1', 'flight': 54},
  {'name': 'TESS', 'flight': 60},
  {'name': 'Bangabandhu-1', 'flight': 61},
  {'name': 'Telstar 19V', 'flight': 65},
  {'name': 'Telstar 18V', 'flight': 68},
  {'name': 'CRS-16', 'flight': 72},
  {'name': 'ArabSat 6A', 'flight': 77},
  {'name': 'CRS-17', 'flight': 78},
  {'name': 'Starlink v0.9', 'flight': 79},
  {'name': 'STP-2', 'flight': 81},
  {'name': 'Starlink 2', 'flight': 87},
  {'name': 'Starlink 3', 'flight': 89},
  {'name': 'Starlink 4', 'flight': 90}],
 [{'name': 'CRS-5', 'flight': 19},
  {'name': 'DSCOVR', 'flight': 20},
  {'name': 'CRS-6', 'flight': 22},
  {'name': 'CRS-7', 'flight': 24},
  {'name': 'SES-9', 'flight': 27},
  {'name': 'CRS-8', 'flight': 28},
  {'name': 'JCSAT-2B', 'flight': 29},
  {'name': 'Thaicom 8', 'flight': 30},
  {'name': 'ABS-2A / Eutelsat 117W B', 'flight': 31},
  {'name': 'CRS-9', 'flight': 32},
  {'name': 'JCSAT-16', 'flight': 33},
  {'name': 'SES-10', 'flight': 38},
  {'name': 'NROL-76', 'flight': 39},
  {'name': 'BulgariaSat-1', 'flight': 42},
  {'name': 'Falcon Heavy Test Flight', 'flight': 55},
  {'name': 'ArabSat 6A', 'flight': 77},
  {'name': 'Starlink v0.9', 'flight': 79},
  {'name': 'Crew Dragon In Flight Abort Test', 'flight': 88}],
 [{'name': 'SES-11 / Echostar 105', 'flight': 49},
  {'name': 'KoreaSat 5A', 'flight': 50},
  {'name': 'Falcon Heavy Test Flight', 'flight': 55},
  {'name': 'TESS', 'flight': 60},
  {'name': 'Telstar 19V', 'flight': 65},
  {'name': 'Merah Putih', 'flight': 67},
  {'name': 'Telstar 18V', 'flight': 68},
  {'name': 'Es’hail 2', 'flight': 70},
  {'name': 'Starlink 2', 'flight': 87},
  {'name': 'Starlink 3', 'flight': 89},
  {'name': 'Starlink 4', 'flight': 90}],
 [{'name': 'ArabSat 6A', 'flight': 77},
  {'name': 'CRS-17', 'flight': 78},
  {'name': 'STP-2', 'flight': 81}],
 [{'name': 'CRS-5', 'flight': 19}, {'name': 'CRS-6', 'flight': 22}],
 [{'name': 'Jason 3', 'flight': 26},
  {'name': 'Iridium NEXT Mission 1', 'flight': 35},
  {'name': 'Iridium NEXT Mission 2', 'flight': 43},
  {'name': 'FormoSat-5', 'flight': 46},
  {'name': 'Iridium NEXT Mission 3', 'flight': 48},
  {'name': 'Iridium NEXT Mission 7', 'flight': 66},
  {'name': 'SSO-A', 'flight': 71},
  {'name': 'Iridium NEXT Mission 8', 'flight': 74}],
 [{'name': 'Iridium NEXT Mission 2', 'flight': 43}],
 [{'name': 'CRS-5', 'flight': 19},
  {'name': 'CRS-6', 'flight': 22},
  {'name': 'Jason 3', 'flight': 26},
  {'name': 'CRS-8', 'flight': 28},
  {'name': 'CRS-9', 'flight': 32},
  {'name': 'Iridium NEXT Mission 1', 'flight': 35},
  {'name': 'CRS-10', 'flight': 36},
  {'name': 'CRS-11', 'flight': 41},
  {'name': 'Iridium NEXT Mission 2', 'flight': 43},
  {'name': 'CRS-12', 'flight': 45},
  {'name': 'CRS-13', 'flight': 51},
  {'name': 'CRS-14', 'flight': 59},
  {'name': 'CRS-15', 'flight': 64},
  {'name': 'Iridium NEXT Mission 7', 'flight': 66},
  {'name': 'SSO-A', 'flight': 71},
  {'name': 'Iridium NEXT Mission 8', 'flight': 74}],
 [{'name': 'SES-9', 'flight': 27},
  {'name': 'CRS-8', 'flight': 28},
  {'name': 'Thaicom 8', 'flight': 30},
  {'name': 'ABS-2A / Eutelsat 117W B', 'flight': 31},
  {'name': 'JCSAT-16', 'flight': 33},
  {'name': 'SES-10', 'flight': 38},
  {'name': 'BulgariaSat-1', 'flight': 42},
  {'name': 'SES-11 / Echostar 105', 'flight': 49},
  {'name': 'KoreaSat 5A', 'flight': 50},
  {'name': 'Falcon Heavy Test Flight', 'flight': 55},
  {'name': 'TESS', 'flight': 60},
  {'name': 'Bangabandhu-1', 'flight': 61},
  {'name': 'Telstar 19V', 'flight': 65},
  {'name': 'Merah Putih', 'flight': 67},
  {'name': 'Telstar 18V', 'flight': 68},
  {'name': 'Es’hail 2', 'flight': 70},
  {'name': 'Nusantara Satu (PSN-6) / S5 / Beresheet', 'flight': 75},
  {'name': 'CCtCap Demo Mission 1', 'flight': 76},
  {'name': 'ArabSat 6A', 'flight': 77},
  {'name': 'CRS-17', 'flight': 78},
  {'name': 'Starlink v0.9', 'flight': 79},
  {'name': 'STP-2', 'flight': 81},
  {'name': 'Starlink 1', 'flight': 84},
  {'name': 'JCSat 18 / Kacific 1', 'flight': 86},
  {'name': 'Starlink 2', 'flight': 87},
  {'name': 'Starlink 3', 'flight': 89},
  {'name': 'Starlink 4', 'flight': 90},
  {'name': 'Starlink 5', 'flight': 92}],
 [{'name': 'Jason 3', 'flight': 26},
  {'name': 'Iridium NEXT Mission 7', 'flight': 66},
  {'name': 'SSO-A', 'flight': 71},
  {'name': 'Iridium NEXT Mission 8', 'flight': 74}],
 [{'name': 'Iridium NEXT Mission 1', 'flight': 35}],
 [{'name': 'Bangabandhu-1', 'flight': 61}]]
```

Далее ловлю ступор и не понимаю, как из этих данных создать DataFrame, который будет содержать столбцы: **NAME** и **FLIGHT**. Желательно при помощи pandas, если это возможно.

Дополнение:
Даже при формировании запроса через pandas:

```
df1 = pd.read_json('https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/ships', orient='columns')
```

Получаю столбец с данными, которые содержит списки словарей:

```
df1['missions']
0     [{'name': 'COTS 1', 'flight': 7}, {'name': 'CO...
1     [{'name': 'CRS-1', 'flight': 9}, {'name': 'CRS...
2                  [{'name': 'CASSIOPE', 'flight': 11}]
3                                                    []
4     [{'name': 'FormoSat-5', 'flight': 46}, {'name'...
5     [{'name': 'CRS-5', 'flight': 19}, {'name': 'DS...
6     [{'name': 'JCSat 18 / Kacific 1', 'flight': 86...
7     [{'name': 'KoreaSat 5A', 'flight': 50}, {'name...
8     [{'name': 'ArabSat 6A', 'flight': 77}, {'name'...
9     [{'name': 'TESS', 'flight': 60}, {'name': 'Ban...
10    [{'name': 'CRS-5', 'flight': 19}, {'name': 'DS...
11    [{'name': 'CRS-5', 'flight': 19}, {'name': 'DS...
12    [{'name': 'SES-11 / Echostar 105', 'flight': 4...
13    [{'name': 'ArabSat 6A', 'flight': 77}, {'name'...
14    [{'name': 'CRS-5', 'flight': 19}, {'name': 'CR...
15    [{'name': 'Jason 3', 'flight': 26}, {'name': '...
16    [{'name': 'Iridium NEXT Mission 2', 'flight': ...
17    [{'name': 'CRS-5', 'flight': 19}, {'name': 'CR...
18    [{'name': 'SES-9', 'flight': 27}, {'name': 'CR...
19    [{'name': 'Jason 3', 'flight': 26}, {'name': '...
20    [{'name': 'Iridium NEXT Mission 1', 'flight': ...
21            [{'name': 'Bangabandhu-1', 'flight': 61}]
Name: missions, dtype: object
```

Comment: По идее для этого отдельный метод есть https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html

Comment: CrazyElf, да, спасибо. Сам только, что нашёл, по даже через этот метод я все равно получаю столбец, который содержит кучу списков со словарями((

Comment: А вот другую функцию попробуйте `pd.json_normalize`, из этого ответа https://stackoverflow.com/a/40589031/8324991

Comment: CrazyElf, большое спасибо. Метод правда работает, но есть нюанс, в случае, если я передаю ему датафрейм, который был открыт через read_json - он выдает ошибку, если делать запрос через API. потом превращать файл в json, и после уже использовать, то все работает.

Comment: Ну да, это вариант именно для работы с изначальным `json`, конечно )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

берете свой df_g и пробуйте сделать следующее:

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(np.concatenate(df_g))
```

получите что-то вроде такого:

```
                       name  flight
0                    COTS 1       7
1                    COTS 2       8
2                     CRS-1       9
3                     CRS-2      10
4                     CRS-3      14
..                      ...     ...
165  Iridium NEXT Mission 7      66
166                   SSO-A      71
167  Iridium NEXT Mission 8      74
168  Iridium NEXT Mission 1      35
169           Bangabandhu-1      61

[170 rows x 2 columns]
```